# mongodb date not matching with the given value

Tags: php, mongodb, date, mongodate

While inserting data into mongodb collection I enter the date as '20-06-2015'
and then convert it to mongo format using:

```
new MongoDate(strtotime(ClearContent(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($start_date)))));
```

But now when I check in database it shows this:

```
ISODate("2015-04-19T18:30:00.000Z")
```

Why does it take the date of yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in mongodb are stored in UTC, and probably you are using a different timezone in PHP

Try setting this at the beginning of your PHP script to use UTC timezone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$dat = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($start_date)), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$get = $dat->getTimestamp();
$date= new MongoDate($get);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
$d = new \MongoDate();
$mongodate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $d->sec);
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$time = strtotime($date) - strtotime($mongodate);
$mongodate_time = new \MongoDate($d->sec + $time, $d->usec);
```